# Relationship types in grails

Tags: grails

What is the use of specifying the relationships in both the classes(hasOne/hasMany AND belongsTo)? Let's take an example

```
class User {
   Profile profile
}

class Profile {
    String name
    String age
    String location
}
```

In this case the `User` has one `Profile`. So how the `hasOne` and `belongsTo` relation will be specified and why?

What is the use of specifying the relationship types? We can just have the object instead of specifying hasOne in User.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either. The `hasOne` and `belongsTo` properties define the relationship between the classes and also adds cascading on deletes saves and updates. If you decide to not use these properties you will have to implement you own cascading effect.

There is an advantage to not using those properties and mapping the relationship when developing a large scale application, as they will cause a performance overhead. This is explained in [Burt Beckwiths blog](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=169)

Answer (score 2):

The use of hasOne and belongsTo control how GORM will treat your relationships. Per the [latest Grails documentation on GORM modeling](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2%20Domain%20Modelling%20in%20GORM) the following are true:

Class User { Profile profile } will result in a many-to-one relationship. Meaning any number of Clients can point to a given profile. No relationship is enforced beyond that.

If the profile is given a static belongsTo = [client:Client] then the relationship becomes a bidirectional many-to-one relationship meaning a Client has one Profile and that profile belongs to the specific client. GORM will now manage persisting the Profile (save, update, and delete) when the Client is saved, updated, or deleted. This also allows you to query through GORM against the Profile and expose the back reference to Client.

The hasOne is used to create a one-to-one relationship. You should apply this on the owning side of the relationship (Client in your example). This will allow GORM to manage persistence of the Profile when the Client is saved, updated, or deleted.

Finally the hasMany allows you to define one-to-many relationship from the owning side (Client in your case) where a client could have many Profiles (silly, but I am using your example properties). Again, this tells GORM that persistence should be handled when the Client is saved, updated, or deleted. There are a few gotchas in regards to this type of relationship, and I highly recommend you read the reference documentation to find out more on how to properly use this type of relationship.

Comment: Should hasOne and belongsTo every both be used?

Comment: No since belongsTo is modeling a many to one relationship while a hasOne is modeling a one to one relationship. Using both would not make sense.